# "However" vs. "On the contarary"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-construction

I wanted to know the difference between **however** and **on the contrary** in the following sentence and why it is better to use however?

> Traumatic events such as serious illness, death, or wars all cause stress. **However/on the contrary**, positive changes in life can also be stressful.

Comment: We don't use _on the contrary_ to say that what is true of one thing can also be true of another. We use it to emphasise something that has just been negated. _John did not inherit his father's great height. On the contrary, he never grew taller than 5 foot 4 inches._

Comment: 'However' might add more detail that changes the picture, but 'on the contrary' is a direct challenge to the veracity.

Comment: Please note that you are required to cite the source of quoted text. If you wrote the example sentence yourself, then you should say so.

Comment: Both terms (specially "on the contrary") are inappropriate in this text. I would rather use "nonetheless" [*in spite of something being said*].

Answer (score 1):

"On the contrary" adds to or makes specific the negative statement that preceded it, or is used for emphasis in a negative response.

> Not all gamers are male. On the contrary, according to a 2020 report by Entertainment Software Association, 41% of gamers in the United States are female.
>
> "Do you hate science fiction?" "On the contrary, I read it all the time."

"However" introduces exceptions to the previous statement, and add-ons that are outside it.

> I usually go to the gym in the mornings. However yesterday I got up late and didn't go.
>
> I usually go to the gym in the mornings. However if I work late I also go in the evenings.

"However" is the best fit for your example, because it states is an add-on outside the original statement. "On the contrary" doesn't fit because the first statement isn't negative and the second doesn't contradict it.